# How to escape value in parameter passed to Oracle SQL script

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have an sql script which is executed using sql plus. It reads input parameters and the beginning looks like this:

```
SET DEFINE ON

DEFINE PARAM1 = '&1'
DEFINE PARAM2 = '&2'

DECLARE
...
```

Now I would like to use this script with the parameters, but I need to use some special characters, particularly `'`

```
@@./update.sql 'value of first param' 'Doesn't work'
                                            ^
--------------------------------------------| Here's the problem
commit;
```

When I do the usual way of concatenation strings like this:

```
'Doesn'||chr(39)||'t work'
```

only `Doesn` appear in the `PARAM2`. Is there some way to escape the character in a way that the sqlplus will read it as a single string?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [escape characters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/text.920/a96518/cqspcl.htm) to achieve this.

`{}` Use braces to escape a string of characters or symbols. Everything within a set of braces in considered part of the escape sequence. When you use braces to escape a single character, the escaped character becomes a separate token in the query.

`\` Use the backslash character to escape a single character or symbol. Only the character immediately following the backslash is escaped.

Some examples on single character escape

```
SELECT 'Frank''s site' AS text FROM DUAL;

TEXT
--------------------
Franks's site
```

Read more [here](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_escape_special_characters_when_writing_sql_queries)

For escaping `&` in SQL*Plus

```
SET ESCAPE '\'
SELECT '\&abc' FROM dual;
```

OR

```
SET SCAN OFF
SELECT '&ABC' x FROM dual;
```

Escaping wild card

```
SELECT name FROM emp 
   WHERE id LIKE '%/_%' ESCAPE '/';

SELECT name FROM emp 
   WHERE id LIKE '%\%%' ESCAPE '\';
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but when I do ```SELECT 'Frank''s site' AS text FROM DUAL;```, then only ```SELECT``` is read in the ```DEFINE PARAM2 = '&2'```

Answer (score 1):

From a shell you should call the script like that:

```
sqlplus user@db/passwd @update 'value of first param' "Doesn't work"
```

(the word *@update* refer to your script which is named update.sql)

Then you have to use literal quoting in your script:

```
DEFINE PARAM2 = q'[&2]';
```

Documentation for literals [can be found here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#sthref344).